# How can I keep an amazon opensearch snapshot in my computer (and not is s3 bucket)

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-opensearch

I have automatic snapshots of my opensearch cluster in amazon and I get list of them using this command:

```
GET _snapshot/cs-automated-enc
```

now I try to find a way to download this snapshot with all of its data to my computer maybe some day I want to restore it back to amazon open search.

Can I have done this ? If no, what other options do I have? Do I have to keep it only in Amazon S3 buckets?

Comment: well, it can be in S3 then you can download it on your computer and delete it from S3. I'd probably keep it in S3 to be honest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a comment mentions on your post, you could potentially simply download the snapshot from S3 and delete it from S3. This would effectively achieve what you want.

However, snapshots are for disaster recovery and backup. I suppose you want to hold the snapshot in S3 as it offers some safety guarantee (as opposed to a personal computer).

Just a guess of your intention - if you want to reduce costs, you could either:

- expire the snapshots from S3 through lifecycle rules, or
- transition them to Glacier (again, through lifecycle rules).